# Navigation Drawer Not Displaying

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu, android-navigation, navigation-drawer

The main activity is displaying but there is no toolbar for navigation drawer.
Ill post my codes below. Im beginner to android and i need your help guys.thanks in advance.

BASE ACTIVITY.class

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    protected RelativeLayout _completeLayout, _activityLayout;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    private Toolbar topToolBar;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer);
        // if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // // on first time display view for first nav item
        // // displayView(0);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = " ";

        topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
        topToolBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        topToolBar.setLogoDescription(" ");


    }

    public void set(String[] navMenuTitles,TypedArray navMenuIcons) {
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = " ";


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items
        if(navMenuIcons==null){
            for(int i=0;i<navMenuTitles.length;i++){
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i]));
            }}else{
            for(int i=0;i<navMenuTitles.length;i++){
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
            }
        }

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        // getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout
                , // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" ");
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" ");
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        // menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Doctor.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Hospital.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

DRAWER.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />


    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <!-- Add content here -->
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_navigation_drawer"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:text="no text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

NavDrawerListAdapter.class

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);


        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());



        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add these lines in your `onCreate()` method

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: the app force close once i run

Answer (score 0):

Drawer Layout only takes 2 children.. one is main content and other is the drawer

In your case you just need to modify your layout file like below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="64dp"
              android:layout_gravity="left"
              android:background="#ffffff"
              android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
          <!-- The main content view -->
         <FrameLayout
              android:id="@+id/content_frame"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" >
          <!-- Add content here -->
         </FrameLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Your Drawerlayout has to be parent layout and rest 2 childs i.e. linearlayout and listview

Also go through this documentation, it may help clear the picture

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html